# template function sum for numeric types and strings

Tags: c++, templates

I am playing around with templates.
I have the following templates to sum the elements of a vector:

```
#include<vector>
#include <iostream>
template <class summable>
summable sum (const std::vector<summable> data, summable initial_value = 0){
    std::cout<<"in the function"<<std::endl;
    for (auto i : data){
        initial_value += i;
    }
    return initial_value;
}
```

and it is working perfectly fine for numeric types. but If I try to pass a vector of strings, I don't get any compilation errors but the function is not being called.
here is my function `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector<string> s {"Hello" , " ", "There" };


    cout<<"Before calling the function\n";
    cout<<sum(s);

    return 0;
}
```

I just get

> Before calling the function

as an output.
if I change the function call to  `cout<<sum(s, string(" "));` the function works as expected. I am guessing it has to do with the way I am defining the default parameter since `0` is not a valid value for a string (I think).
My question is why am I not getting any errors ? since it was able to compile it should run , no ?

Comment: You initialize the string with 0

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: yeah, but then why did not the compiler complain about it ? how can this code compile if it not correct ?

Comment: You may want to initialize the parameter with a default value expressed as `summable initial_value = summable()`

Comment: Initializing std::string with nullptr being UB, anything can happen, but on my Mac with Clang and CLion I get this helpful output:

> Before calling the function
> Process finished with exit code 11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track. For `std::string` the value `0` is the same as `nullptr`, and matches a constructor taking `const char*`.

However, it is undefined behavior to pass a null pointer to that constructor. Undefined behavior means that *anything* can happen.

The standard says:

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

> Requires: `s` points to an array of at least `traits::length(s) + 1` elements of `charT`.
>
> Effects: Constructs an object of class `basic_string` and determines its initial string value from the
>   array of `charT` of length `traits::length(s)` whose first element is designated by `s`, as indicated in
>   Table 67.

So, if `s` is null (or `0`), it doesn't point to an array of `charT`, and the preconditions are violated.

---

And, by the way, you could use `summable{}` as a default value for the parameter. That works for any default constructible type.